# How do I access elements inside of an HTML collection in VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have used the following code to build a collection, inside which I have several items. However, I don't know how to access these items now, or their properties.  For example, one of these items is a checkbox, which has the property Checked, which can be true or false. Things I have tried that have failed:

objCollection.item5

objCollection(5)

objCollection.Item(5)

Here is my code:

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser

'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page
objIE.Navigate "https://secure01b.chase.com/web/auth/dashboard#/dashboard/overviewAccounts/overview/index"

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set objCollection = objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

The end goal of this entire process is to be able to log into this page via a macro to retrieve my credit spending so that I can do some excel data manipulation.

EDIT: Here are the results of running the code, when I watch the collection:
[objCollection Watch Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj8Bd.png)

Comment: How many elements are in `ObjCollection`?  All i can tell from your question is that it's an `iFrame`.

Comment: yup test how many items are in the collection first with objCollection.Count. Also, what is the error message you get with objCollection(5).innerText ?

Comment: And are you sure the iframe index is the correct one?

Comment: @Cyril - my bad, perhaps the attached image will help show what I'm dealing with here.

Comment: @QHarr - With the innerText I get an object Variable or with variable not set.  The count function claims that it is not supported by this object.  Is my objCollection not what I'm supposed to be working with?

Also, I'm fairly certain the iframe index is the correct one, but that's secondary to my main problem of not being able to reference any of the items to do anything with them anyway at this point.

Comment: @QHarr thanks for pointing out; removed the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As QHarr said, the index of the Collection list starts from 0, if you want to find the 5th element, we could use `objCollection(4)` or `objCollection.item(4)`.

Besides, we could also find the special element by using the getElementbyId method, like this:

```
  Dim userText As Object, rememberCheckBox As Object
  Set userText = objIE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementbyId("userId-input-field")
  userText.Value = "AAA"   'set value.

  Set rememberCheckBox = objIE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementbyId("input-useToken")
  rememberCheckBox.Click  'click the useToken checkbox to check it.
```

After using F12 developer tools to check your website elements, I found that you are checking the checkbox by using the `checkbox__input checkbox__input--checked` CSS class, instead of using the `checked` property. You could use F12 developer tools to verify it.

So, if you want to check the checkbox, after finding the checkbox, we could click it to check it. You could refer to the above code, or using the following code:

```
    objCollection.Item(4).Click

    objCollection(4).Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing starts at 0 so if you want the 5th element you need index 4. Also use .item(4)  or just (4)

```
objCollection.item(4)
objCollection(4)
```

Number of items in collection comes from

```
HTMLItemCol.length
```